# Automatically answer call in android 2.1

Tags: android, call, android-2.1-eclair

I am looking for some code to automatically answer incoming call in android 2.1. I have looked on some of the available threads on stack-overflow but they do not seem to work for Android 2.1.

Can anybody give some peace of code to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Set up communication with the telephony service (thanks to Tedd's Droid Tools!)

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService;
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
// Silence the ringer and answer the call!
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
```

Refer this [LINK1](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java) [LINK2](http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html)

Comment: ITelephony is not a part of Android 2.1. Where is it located. Is it a third party class?